# Use of the Python Language

Tags: python, shell, scripting, programming-languages, splunk

I have been studying Python at work for a week now and it seems very interesting, I started using it in order to create Extra Search functions for Splunk.

My Question is, what else can you do with it?, is it only a Script Language?, if so what type of scripts can I create and use?

To what extent should I learn Python in order to begin writing usable scripts?

I can write a Shell Korn script to Query a MySql Database, Can I do the same with Python?

Comment: Why is everyone voting down on my question?, As a person new to Python I have the right to ask this question!

Comment: It's easier to answer specific questions like "How do I query MySQL with Python?" rather than "What I can do with Python?".

Answer (score 6):

You can pretty much do anything with Python that you can do with `ksh`, only easier (shells have a lot of stuff built in but many scripts will "reach out" to helpers like `grep`, `sed` `awk`, and so forth, to do grunt work).

Python also comes with an [insanely large library](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/index.html) (just like Java and C#) and [plenty of add-on modules](http://pypi.python.org/pypi), both of which also include database stuff.

You don't *have* to learn Python to be able to script successfully, there's a large array of solutions for this. But Python *is* a useful weapon to have in your arsenal.

Bottom, it's quite able to handle a huge number of tasks, including the specific one you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for your Cool answer, But what type of solutions are you talking about for Scripting?

Comment: Python, Perl, ksh, bash, csh, and any of the huge variety of others. Some have niches (Ruby, PHP, etc) but I'm sure even those could be bent to the task of general purpose shells.

Answer (score 5):

Aloha!

The obnoxious answer is that Python like other languages are turing complete and you can write program in it. But that probably doesn't answer your question. ;-)

First however, a tip: Stop think in terms of scripting vs real programming languages. Python, just like Java, Perl, Ruby, LISP, Scala, Lua, Cloujure are just as much real programming languages as C, C++, Fortran etc. The main difference is what they are running on. C for example can run on "bare metal", that is basically be translated to sequences of instructions that can be executed by the native/real CPU. Python, Java etc relies on a virtual machine to execute their instructions. The VM is then run by the real CPU.

The VM costs some performance, but add things like portability, dynamic behaviour (introspection, duck typing etc) that make the language and systems written in it very efficent in ways it is harder to do (but not impossible - remember Turing completeness) in for example C.

With that in min (Python is a real programming language) you might not be surprised to learn that Python can be and is used for things like:

- Network servers and network applications. Look at the great Twisted networking framework and look and beautiful applications like Trac.
- Large scale, professional distributed version control. Mercurial (Hg) is written entirely in Python and is able to handle huge, active projects with developers on a global level.
- Compilers, languages and virtual machines. There is actually a virtual machine able to run Python written in Python(!). The machine called Pypy use some of the dynamic functionality of the language to enhance the performance.

Pypy is really a groovy concept - having the machine you are running your code in a language that can be modified at runtime - basically rebuilding the "hardware" from your application to enhance the machine to at the whim of the application. (And yes, I'm aware that all LISP guys yawn at this point - nothing new but still very, very groovy)

There you have it, some IMHO good, everything but simplistic, non-professional applications. Now start reading up on Python.org about the advanced features of the language and amazing functionality readily available in the standard lib. Your programming life will thank you for it.

Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

To answer your questions in order:

1. Everything.
2. No.
3. Any.
4. As much as possible.
5. Yes.

Comment: For answer Number 5: Can you give me an example?

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/

Answer (score 2):

Start [here](http://www.python.org/)